# Losing session after vagrant destroy/up with Symfony

Tags: symfony, session, vagrant

I have Symfony application running on vagrant with shared folders.

Problem is that for my teammates after they provision vagrant everything works fine but I can't login.

After little investigation i came to conclusion it is a session that is lost.
I'm using standard configuration for session.

I was successfully authenticated but after redirection the session values were not there any more.

With xdebug i confirmed that authentication works well i get token with authenticated true,
in access logs i can see that after login_check next request is to home page for logged in users but i am redirected back to login page because i am not authenticated any more then.

I have checked cache directory, files are created there, gave it 777 just in case anyway.

I tried to recreate vagrant on some old local branch when everything was working well but same thing happens.

I have removed vagrant and VirtualBox and installed latest versions, no luck again.

I am the only one affected, my workmates can checkout master brach, vagrant up and it works for them well.

Same thing happens in different browsers. Other change i did lately was OS upgrade to Yosemite (osx)

Any idea where to look for a cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end i solved it by setting session handler to default from php.ini

in config.yml

```
  session:
    handler_id: ~
```

there was a race condition because of vagrant shared folders

From: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7885

> The shared vagrant folder has to do a lot of syncing and is much
>   slower than the rest of the folders on the VM. I think what happens is
>   Symfony logs the user in, writes a session file then goes to read that
>   session file and it's not there yet (because the folder is slow). At
>   this point Symfony loses the session and the user is effectively
>   logged back out. Moving the session cache to a faster folder fixes the
>   issue since the file is there when Symfony expects it. For me it was
>   actually working on a computer with a SSD (faster IO) and failing on a
>   computer with a traditional HDD. The SSD was fast enough to be able to
>   support caching to the shared folder but the HDD couldn't keep up.
>   Moving the cache outside of the shared folder fixes it.